# Batch convert folder with various size PNG images to 16x16 PNG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, png, resize

Is there any tools/method available in either Adobe Illustrator, Photoshop or any other tool that can batch convert a folder with PNG images of multiple sizes to PNG images of 16x16 pixels?

Thanks for your guidance and help!

Comment: 16 x 16 what?  Inches, pixels, millimetres, miles?

Comment: sincerest apologies...16x16 pixels

Comment: You do realise that's absolutely tiny and very low resolution, right?  It's smaller than an icon. In Photoshop simply record an action, do Image > Image size, save as PNG, stop recording, then apply using File > Automate > Batch.

Comment: Most decent 16px artwork needs to be done manually pixel by pixel. Primarily because any auto-reduction will result in a great deal of anti-aliasing making the original image hard to distinguish.

Comment: @Scott - yup, will likely look horrible if you just resize a larger image.

Comment: Practically [unrecognisable](https://imgur.com/g4T1wAu), most likely, even when [zoomed in](https://imgur.com/Nhr0d8l)